# Div content align problems

Tags: html, css, alignment

I don't have much experience with HTML and CSS. I've got some problems with aligning my div content. The text (Oculus Rift, Next-generation Virtual Reality) has to be in line with de mouse scroll button, in the bottom right. But the text overlaps the div above (my sticky header). I just can't get it to work. I've hosted the site [over here](http://informatica.thebrandcode.nl/). I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8gXr.png).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>InGadget | D&#233; site voor al uw gadget nieuws!</title>

<meta name = "keywords" content = "InGadget | D&#233; site voor al uw gadget nieuws!" />
<meta name = "description" content = "InGadget is d&#233; site voor alles over gadgets." />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/animatescroll.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script>
        function init() {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
                var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    shrinkOn = 100,
                    header = document.querySelector(".navbar");
                if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                    classie.add(header,"scroll");
                } else {
                    if (classie.has(header,"scroll")) {
                        classie.remove(header,"scroll");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        window.onload = init();
</script>

<script>
    function logoSwitch () {
        $('.altLogo').each(function() {
            $(this).css('top',
                        $('.startLogo').offset().top -  $(this).closest('.row').offset().top
                       );
        });
    };

    $(document).scroll(function() {logoSwitch();});

    logoSwitch();
</script>

</head>
<body>
            <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <a id="logo" href="index.html"></a>
                <div class="nav">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">Nieuws</a>
                    <a href="#">Forum</a>
                    <a href="#">Things I &#10084;</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-content">
            <h1>Oculus Rift<br>
                Next-generation Virtual Reality.</h1>
            <div class="mouse-icon" onclick="$('.section1').animatescroll();" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <div class="wheel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section1">
        Placeholder
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* BASICS */
@font-face {
    font-family: Neusa-SemiBold;
    src: url(fonts/neusa/Neusa-SemiBold.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Neusa-ExtraBold;
    src: url(fonts/neusa/Neusa-ExtraBold.otf);
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

/* NAVBAR */
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.6s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.6s;
    -o-transition: height 0.6s;
    transition: height 0.6s;
}

#logo {
    width: 275px;
    height: 150px;
    background: transparent url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    float: left;
}

.scroll #logo {
    background-image: url(images/logo2.png);
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    right: 0px;
}

.nav a {
    line-height: 75px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;    
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* STICKY NAVBAR */

.navbar.scroll {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 75px;
}

.navbar.scroll#logo {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    background: transparent url(images/logo2.png) left top no-repeat;
}

.navbar.scroll .nav a {
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 75px; }

/* SECTIONS */
.header {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(to top right,
            rgba(255, 65, 54, 0.5),
            rgba(24, 0, 255, 0.5)
        ),
        url(nieuws/VR/images/oculusrift.jpg) fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.header-content h1 {
    font-family: 'Neusa-ExtraBold', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
}

.section1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height: 500px;
}

/* MOUSE ICON */
.mouse-icon {
    border: 4px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 32px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
}

.mouse-icon .wheel {
    -webkit-animation-name: scrolling;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-name: scrolling;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.mouse-icon .wheel {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 6px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 4px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scrolling    {
    0%   { top:5px;  opacity: 0;}
    30%  { top:10px; opacity: 1;}
    100% { top:25px; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes scrolling    {
    0%   { top:5px;  opacity: 0;}
    30%  { top:10px; opacity: 1;}
    100% { top:25px; opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Please don't be funny @PraveenKumar

Comment: Ha ha... Sure... I am still working on your stuff... Will try to post a solution wait.

Comment: Ha ha ha.. I was just kidding man. Yes, it was that.

Comment: did you tried  "position:absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 2%;" to .header-content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the 'header-content' div inside another div with class 'header-content-container' and add this CSS:

```
.header-content-container {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-content h1{
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.mouse-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    bottom; 20px;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the h1 and mouseicon absolute to the bottom

```
.mouse-icon {
    border: 4px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 32px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom; 10px;
}

.header-content h1 {
    font-family: 'Neusa-ExtraBold', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom; 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
    position:relative;
}
.header-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 45px;
}
```

Use these styles along with your other css styles. Please Let me know if you have any other requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/qs1qyL9c/

```
.header-content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;

}
```